# CSS Only / Show multiple divs on checked radiobutton

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to show 2 (or more) div's on a checked radio button. I am not very experienced, am learning.
It works to show one div. But I can't seem to get the next one shown. I've tried googling and searching Stackoverflow but have not found a solution.

Example html:

```
<div id="div1">
<h3>Question 1</h3>
<input id="Radio1" name="Radio1" type="radio" value="Radio1"> <label for="Radio1">Yes</label>
<p>Text 1</p>
</div>

<div id="div2">
<h3>Question 2</h3>
<input id="Radio2" name="Radio2" type="radio" value="Radio2"> <label for="Radio2">Yes</label>
<p>Text 2</p>
</div>

<div id="div3">
<h3>Question 3</h3>
<input id="Radio3" name="Radio3" type="radio" value="Radio3"> <label for="Radio3">Yes</label>
<p>Text 3</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  #div2 {
    display:none;
  }
  #div3 {
    display:none;
  }
 input#Radio1:checked ~ #Div2 {
    display: block;
  }
```

So as mentioned, this works to show Div2 when radio1 is checked. But how do I expand or add a css rule to also show div3 when radio1 is checked. I do not want to incorporate question 3 in div2 for other reasons. 
Is this possible with CSS only?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the community, First of all there is no HTML tags like div1 and div2. You need to assign id as "div1", "div2". Also css file is wrong. #div3 is not closed with closing braces.

Comment: I'm sorry for the sloppy codeblocks. But the divs have ID's in reality. The code was just for indication purposes. So <Div id="Div1"> etc and the css has closing braces. I've editted the code above